# Add own design to button whilst having a theme

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my application which at the moment has theme it is calling from:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/WhistlerBlue.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

I want to create an invisible button behind a label but everytime I add a button it is making it like every other button.

```
<Button x:Name="btnHelp"
        Content="Help"
        Foreground="#FF7E8385"
        FontFamily="Calibri"
        FontSize="18"
        Margin="25,11,0,0"
        Click="btnHelp_Click"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Padding="0" />
<GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Height="30"
              Margin="10,10,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="1"
              Background="#FFB2B2B2"
              Focusable="False" 
              IsTabStop="False"
              IsEnabled="False"/>
<Button x:Name="btnSettings"
        Content="Settings"
        Foreground="#FF7E8385"
        FontFamily="Calibri"
        FontSize="18"
        Margin="10,11,0,0"
        Click="btnSettings_Click">
</Button>
```

The code above is my buttons and I have tried adding in `Background ="Transparent"` but this does nothing I have also tried `Background = "{x:Null}"` and this does nothing.

I am new and learning WPF so any help would be very helpful.

EDIT: This is a picture of the actual exception:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffzNa.png

The `Master` is the `Generic` page that I created so that I don't have duplicate code.

I don't know if this makes a difference but at the top of the `Master` page it has a `Style` set like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Menu Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                        <Menu.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFB3DDF2" Offset="1.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD6E9F4" Offset="0.0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Menu.Background>
                        <Button x:Name="btnHelp" Content="Help" Foreground="#FF7E8385" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" Margin="25,11,0,0" Click="btnHelp_Click" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource TransButtonStyle}" />
                        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1" Background="#FFB2B2B2" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" IsEnabled="False"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnSettings" Content="Settings" Foreground="#FF7E8385" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" Margin="10,11,0,0" Click="btnSettings_Click">
                        </Button>
```

Comment: Most probably your Theme file has defined a `ControlTemplate` for `Button` where `Background` is hardcoded or coming from some resource rather than a `TemplateBinding`. You'll need to define your own `ControlTemplate` if that is the case.

Comment: @Mathew So, If I go into my Theme to find the `ControlTemplate` for the button, can I add 2 different templates for a button and then call the one I want in the XAML?

Comment: Yes you can. The existing one will be without a key. You can create one with a key and apply it using `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` extension.

Comment: @Mathew Tried doing this with the answer below but I get an exception `Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.`

Comment: Can you update the `Style` or `ControlTemplate` you just created? Check the `InnerException` for the actual error.

Comment: @Mathew I added some information, How do I check the `InnerException` if I haven't already posted how?

Comment: I hope `TransButtonStyle` is the new style you just created. If so, Can you show how that is declared?

Answer (score 0):

If you search through the `WhistlerBlue.xaml` `resource` you will probably find something similar to the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">...</Style>
```

This applies that particular styling to any control that derives from the `Button` type, therefore if you want other `Button` controls to look different you will need to either alter the styling in that `resource`, or create your own style.

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<!-- define your settings -->
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

Then apply it to your `Button` controls:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your code, everything seems to work but now when I run my code, there is an error saying `Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.`

Comment: probably you have used the wrong key in your Style or did not provide a key at all.

Comment: @Herm I have used the correct key and tried changing the name, it still does not work?

Comment: @user3110814 - Can you provide the exact exception/stacktrace.  Sounds like it is expecting a value for some property that is not being specified.

Comment: @Veleous I have edited the question but how do I find the `Exact exception/stacktrace`

Comment: @user3110814 - Click the `View Exception Detail` link in the `Actions` box.